# TGS-407 - Course run not found error while doing individual enrollment

Tags: peoplesoft, ssg

I am getting 'TGS-407 - Course run not found' while trying to upload individual student enrollment to SSG.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Please add more details to your question

Comment: I am sending a student enrollment data from PeopleSoft to SSG (SkillsFuture Singapore) using JSON API. While I am invoking student enrollment upload API from PeopleSoft system then getting an error ( TGS-407 - Course run not found).

Comment: This is an error on SSG then, test the payload with postman